# Нагрузочное тестирование Jmeter + GRPC

Tags: jmeter, grpc

Пытаюсь провести нагрузочное тестирование для микросервиса через GRPC.
Апи для сервиса реализовано через GRPC
Так как GRPC не всходит в базовый пакет Jmeter то прикрутил библиотеку которую нашел на  просторах интернета. - https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request

К сожалению README скудный и непонятно как прикрутить правильно свои сервисы к этой библиотеке

Вот у меня есть  и клиентская и серверная  часть микросервиса на гитхабе
Я могу получить прото файлы

Может быть кто нибудь имеет опыт подобной сборки и обьяснит как правильно указать файлы в  Folder path of proto files использованную в этом мануале. Извиняюсь но прав прикреплять скрины у меня нет

Comment: Если кому то понадобится основной момент в том чтобы получить полную структуру прото файлов проекта и всех связанных с ним сторонних проектов, а далее  сформировать соответственно импортам внутри прото файлов  расположение всех остальных прото файлов. Вкратце надо сформировать структуру прото файлов  и указать правильно корень прото директории)) Понимаю что непонятно, обьяснить текстом лучше не могу. И еще. Если внутри прото файлов  есть ссылки на функции, то надо внутри директорий хранить не только прото файлы но и файлы с расширением .class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому то понадобится основной момент в том чтобы получить полную структуру прото файлов проекта и всех связанных с ним сторонних проектов, а далее сформировать соответственно импортам внутри прото файлов расположение всех остальных прото файлов. Вкратце надо сформировать структуру прото файлов и указать правильно корень прото директории)) Понимаю что непонятно, обьяснить текстом лучше не могу. И еще. Если внутри прото файлов есть ссылки на функции, то надо внутри директорий хранить не только прото файлы но и файлы с расширением .class